# Including the count in a query result

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, subquery

I have two tables, `customer` and `people`, related on `customer_id`.  I'd like a query result showing all customers with > 500 people, including that count of people.  I'm getting the result fine, but I need help including the count within the result.

This is my query, which runs fine other than that it doesn't return the count:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `customer_id`, `name`, `city`, `state`, `country`
FROM `customer`
WHERE `customer_id` IN 
(
    SELECT `customer_id`
    FROM `people`
    GROUP BY `customer_id`
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 500
)
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply join the subquery instead of using it for filtering; this way, its result is available in the outer query:

```
SELECT c.*, p.no_people
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT customer_id, count(*) no_people 
    FROM people 
    GROUP BY customer_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 500
) p on p.customer_id = c.customer_id
```